# shared drive map with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script which uses the following command:

```
net use L: \\\ServerName\folder /persistent:yes
```

As of now I am hard coding the server name and the shared path in the batch file.
To make this more generic I have done following:

```
@echo off
set /p path_folder = \\\ServerName\Software
echo %path_folder%
net use L: %path_folder% /persistent:yes
```

But when I execute the above It does not map the drive.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: An UNC path usually starts with `\\ ` but not `\\\ `...

Comment: Also in a `set` ***don't*** put spaces around the equal sign. They become part of the variable name/content. So ***your*** variable is named "path_folder " See `set path_folder`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: Solution is below.

@echo off

set path_folder=%1

echo %path_folder%

net use L: %path_folder% /persistent:yes

net use L: /delete

cd L:

In my previous post  there is some space before and after the "=" sign and that caused the issue.
My Idea was to replace %1 as as in put from any of the external programs.